# Python program to give me numbers on the left with their sum on the right while having interchanged symbols in each line up to n (n=6)

Tags: python, sorting, variables, sum, output

[image: Python program sum]

Here's the picture of the program/ how it should work, it should display 1*1 then 12$3 < 3 is the sum of 1+2.. we only got to for loop.

I have tried a lot of solutions and this is what i got to at the end, for some reason i can't copy and paste it here without the code deleting whatever i had here..[image: Python trying to solve]
also the output currently is:[image: output]

please help and thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement this idea this way:

```py
def func(n: int):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        nsum = 0  # Sum of numbers in nested loop.
        last = 0  # Last number added to 'nsum'.
        string = ''  # Final string which is then printed.
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            nsum   += j  # Add to total sum.
            string += str(j)  # Add to final string.
            last   = j  # Set last number to current.
        # Decide if either asterisk (*) or dollar ($) should be included
        # in final message, after it append total sum.
        string += ('*' if last % 2 else '$') + str(nsum)
        print(string)
 
func(6)
```